# Selection.ShapeRange isn't working with ActiveX CommandButton

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub sampleButton_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

With Selection.ShapeRange
    If .Type = msoGroup Then
        Call setStyleTest(.GroupItems(.GroupItems.Count))
    Else
        For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            Call setStyleTest(shp)
        Next shp
    End If
End With
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

I use ActiveX CommandButton and have a problem with a testing selection of ShapeRange. What should I change/fix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the selection a valid Shape range object? If not the else can't handle it, you need to use an "on error" statement

Comment: yes. When I select the shape object and debug it, the problem is in the With Selection.ShapeRange.
If I change the active-X button with shape button(assign it in macro and use the code below), the program run smoothly. It's confusing

Comment: use `Selection.shaperange(1)` , you can also affect it to a Shape Type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problem Explanation***

The CommandButton does not have the property `ShapeRange`

[image: Shape Properties]

Hence, the error will always arise

[image: CommandButton invalid property]

In the other hand, if you change the object for a button -the one under form collection- you will not have that problem because that property exists in that object

[image: Button Object Model]

Note that, even if they resemble in appearance, they are totally different objects, as such, one property may not exist in the other one or behave like in the other.
More info about what you can do -and how to do it- with this button can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835842.aspx)

***Solution/workaround***

I can see that you are calling another sub to "personalize" the button created, since it is unknown, you would need to change in that according to the object in order to provide the desired format.
You would also need to invert the order in your code for the correct handling

```
...
    If .Type = msoGroup Then
With Selection.ShapeRange
...
```

***Further thoughts***

I cannot possible think about a scenario where you would need to use active X instead of form button collection, so I would suggest to change all the buttons to that.

Answer (score 0):

It is working just fine for me

[image]

The value of `msoGroup` is `6`

Till the time the group is selected your code will work. Once you are out of design mode and the group is not selected, your code will not work.

And yes the above two command buttons are ActiveX and not Form Controls

[image]

**My suggestion**: Stick to Form controls.